# Implicit cast operator and the equality operator

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion

Say I have a simple object which supports implicit casting to System.String

```
public sealed class CompanyCode
{
    public CompanyCode(String value)
    {
        { Regex validation on value format }
        _value = value;
    }

    readonly String _value;

    public override String ToString() => _value;

    static public implicit operator String(CompanyCode code) =>
        code?.ToString();
}
```

Now lets say in another part of my program I perform a comparison with a string:

```
var companyCode = { some company code object }

if (companyCode == "MSFTUKCAMBS")
    // do something...
```

What is the compiler doing with the `==` operator? Is it implicitly casting companyCode to a string and running the `System.String ==` implementation? Is it using the `System.Object ==` implementation? Or will the compiler just complain at me? (I don't have a compiler to check this right now).

As far as I can see I have a couple of other options.

- Implement an `==(String x)` operator on CompanyCode.
- Implement the `IEquatable<String>` interface on CompanyCode.

Would any (or both) of these options be preferable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will implicitly cast to a string and check equality using the string's == operator.
For the case you show - every way you offered is suitable, but every way has a different purpose and meaning.

Implicitly conversion should usually be avoided.
Implementing the == is to allow comparing with a string,
and IEquatable is simply to allow using the class as type IEquatable, for outside code references. The IEquatable may very well just return the == result.

For this case, I would choose the == operator overloading, unless you have any other purpose for using implicit conversion.

Also, if you use implicit conversions, it will be a bit uglier code-wise but smarter robust-wise to overload an EXPLICIT conversion, and not an implicit one, so whenever one wants to convert your class to a string, he will have to cast it using (string)obj, which is also a good reminder for whats really happening in the code.

Comment: Re-visiting this question several years later, and I now think this is the best answer. As we know, implicit conversions should be lossless. I mentioned in my comments to Jons answer that I wanted the class behaviour to always be tied to the string value. As such, the implicit conversion to string was in fact lossy. Making the conversion explicit makes the code much clearer.

Answer (score 5):

> Say I have a simple object which supports implicit casting to System.String

I would question this design decision to start with. The fact that it's brought up this question of operator overloading suggests that your colleagues will be asking the same sort of questions. I don't even know the answer (in terms of what the compiler will do) off the top of my head.

I definitely *wouldn't* suggest implementing `IEquatable<string>`, as then `x.Equals(y)` won't be symmetric with `y.Equals(x)`. You *could* implement two overloads of `==` in your class, both ways round... but then it wouldn't be consistent with `Equals`.

I would suggest just having a property called `Value` or `Code` of type string, then you can use:

```
if (companyCode.Value == "MSFTUKCAMBS")
```

and it will be immediately clear what that means.

Basically, I think the situations where implicit conversions are appropriate are very few and far between.

From the [Design Guidelines for Class Library Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229033.aspx)

> Do not provide a conversion operator if such conversion is not clearly expected by the end users.

Is there such a clear expectation here?

Comment: +1 for the caveats of the implicit casting overload. I'd like to add on top of "clearly expected" that implicit casting should be lossless and not require conversion. Nor should it raise any exceptions.

Comment: I appreciate your point on the operators, I may well be over engineering this slightly. I'll tell you why I'm reluctant to expose the _value field - the purpose of this object is that a simple string value is tied together with bits of logic (such as the regex validation). By exposing the _value field I'm essentially allowing people to detach the value from the logic, losing the benefit of having them tied together in the first place. In the existing code base these company codes are passed around as strings, and the validation (&other) logic is heavily duplicated. I'm quite keen to stop this.

Comment: @MattDavey: I'm not suggesting that you expose anything you're not already exposing: you don't even need an extra property, given that clients *could* just call `ToString()`. I certainly wasn't suggesting making it *writable*.

Comment: @JonSkeet What I'm worried about is people detaching the value from the behaviour (via an exposed _value or ToString) somewhere high up the call stack, and then passing the raw value down - leading to the same situation I'm in now where the behaviour is duplicated. Is there any way I can make sure the behaviour follows the value wherever it goes while still allowing string comparison?

Answer (score 1):

I personally would suggest do not use `operator overloading`, in *these cases*. It's kind of confusing looking on the code, to understand what is going on.

It's a much better, imo, having some function that esplicitly *manifests* comparison operation, or, like Jon suggests, use a property.

In short make it clear for the reader of your code what you're gonna to compare.

Comment: Hi Tigran. When you say a function that manifests a comparison - do you mean a property that exposes a Comparison delegate, where one of the operands has been curried to the internal _value field?

Comment: @MattDavey: I mean (say) IComparable implementation and call for compare, so I see it calls compare and *intent* to see some custom logic (which is not *intended* when I see ==).

Comment: Yeah, I see that being essentially the same as the IEquatable implementation which Jon recommended against. Is there a specific reason that IComparable would be preferable to IEquatable?

Comment: @MattDavey: no, there is no particular reasons, if not *architectual*. You can choose what you want, important is make a *custom comparison* you make to a reader esplicitly clear, which is not using == operator overloading.

Comment: I agree with you :) But I also trust Jons opinion - this is a dilemma!

Comment: @MattDavey: mine and Jon's answer are *basically* the same. I don't say: "YOU MUST USE A FUNCTIONS!. I say, make a comparison esplicitly clear. Jon suggests use a property so when I see obj.PropertyString == "value", it's a absolutely clear what is going on here. We are talkng about the same stuff.

Comment: I do see the two suggestions as being slightly different. From my view the distinction is - is the comparison a behaviour of the CompanyCode class, or a behaviour of the String class? I prefer the former in this case :)

Comment: @MattDavey: my idea: it's a behaviour of CompanyCode class. CompanyCode is a custom class, so should make it explicit what and how  it want to compare.