# C# how to make a class that behave like Nullable<T>

Tags: c#, class, type-conversion, implicit-conversion, conversion-operator

Given the code:

```
public class Filter<T>
{
    private bool selected = false;
    public bool Selected { get { return selected; } }

    private T value;
    public T Value { get{ return this.value; } set { this.value = value; selected = true; }
}     

public class Test
{
    public void filter()
    {
        DateTime a= new DateTime();
        Nullable<DateTime> b = new DateTime(); //Work Like a Charm
        Filter<DateTime> c = new DateTime(); //Dosent Work
    }
}
```

In `Nullable<T>` the `new DateTime()` can be assigned directly into the variable. In my class, it doesn't work. I want to understand what I'm missing.

I think that is something simple. But I couldn't put it on words to find the answer.

Comment: `Nullable<T>` is a special case that has a special treatment in the CLR and the compilers of .net languages

Comment: Part of the problem you'll have with finding identical semantics is that `Nullable<T>` is a `struct`, not a `class`.

Comment: @ShaniElharrar his question is not a special case at all because it is just about implicit conversions.

Comment: @csharpler - That's one way to go. Don't expect great performance from implicit conversions.

Comment: @ShaniElharrar why would implicit conversions degrade performance? All I see is the conversion might some slow code, and a consumer don't noticing the conversion, and so doing this kind of assignment several times/in inappropriate places. But the problem I can see, is not really in the implicit conversions operator, and is in the implementation and lack of knowledge in a codebases

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to implement [implicit operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public static implicit operator Filter<T>(T value)
{
    return new Filter<T>() { Value = value };
}
```

An implicit operator will allow you to cast the types without explicitly writing `Filter<T> filter = (Filter<T>)value;` (explicit cast), but rather only `Filter<T> filter = value;` (implicit cast).

Comment: @Clint no constructor was defined in the OP's code, so `return new Filter<T>(value);` won't compile because only the constructor without parameters is accessible.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use an implict conversion operator:

See: [Implicit cast operator and the equality operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837160/implicit-cast-operator-and-the-equality-operator)

This allows you to write code to construct your custom type from another type.